Force child element to display outside overflow hidden container
I'm trying to solve this css problem:
I have a list of items contained in a scrolling container (overflow-y: scroll / overflow-x: hidden)
each of this items have a child div (popup). I need to display this child element outside the scrolling container but the position must be relative to the item div.
I can't manage to find a way to display those childs elements outside the overflow hidden of the scroll container.
If anyone has a solution,
thank you so much.
What I'm trying to do
Simplified exemple :
https://jsfiddle.net/zbvwjq1s/35/


.container{
  position: relative;
  background-color:black;
  width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.scroll-container{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: 250px;
  background-color:red;
}
.item{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:green;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  right:-80px;
  width:80px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:blue;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.item:hover .popup {
  visibility:visible;
}
<div class='container'>
    <div class='scroll-container'>
        <div class='item'>
            <div class='popup'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <div class='popup'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <div class='popup'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <div class='popup'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <div class='popup'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <div class='popup'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <div class='popup'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




css-tricks.com: Popping Out of Hidden Overflow

Given you need the CSS overflow to make the list scrollable, and the provided image, actually all you need is one single (right) popup. Create a common container for the list and the popup, then with JS on a LI item click get the item data and re-populate the details popup.

@RokoC.Buljan Yes I thought about this option. Maybe is not very clear on the screenshot but the popup must be placed relative to the item and not always centered like on this specific exemple.

@ThéoEschlimann there's no reason to not make it centered as long as you have the UX tiny LI arrow pointing to it. Anyways, the idea remains the same, still using JS - if really needed you can than move the Y position of that popup upon opening it.

@RokoC.Buljan yes you are right, I'm not making the designs choices so I'll ask for implementing this solution wich seems the easier. Thanks.
